# ClamXav not protecting against Malware and Trojans, what to do

Tags: snow-leopard, software-recommendation, applications, mac, anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anti-virus comparison for Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4387/anti-virus-comparison-for-mac-os-x)

I am using ClamXav for protecting my Mac from Antivirus.

But I don't think that it protects from Malware, Spyware, or Trojans.

So, what are free (or paid :( ) options available for above mentioned threats.

If comparison is available, with suggestions for choosing right product, then it would be like icing on cake.

Comment: @Philip Regan: Linked question is about Antivirus, I was looking for product that can protect my mac against malware and trojan horses. Till my knowledge is there, Clamxav does not protect/detect malware or trojan

Comment: Anti-virus typically includes coverage for trojans, at least. Malware is a different issue entirely. But I will reopen this.

Comment: You should only learn to install software from reliable sources and you will not need any antivirus. There is no antivirus on the market that can fully protect you, and it will never be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system you're using (OS X) **is** the best protection against Malware, Spyware and Trojans.

Just be careful that you aren't putting in your password for anything you're not sure about.

I've run my Mac systems for many years without *any* anti-virus or other "protective" software.  I'm simply just careful with what I install, and ensure it comes from reputable sources.

By no means am I saying that the Mac is 100% uncompromisable.  Just saying that if you are careful, the chances of problems are minuscule and not worth the concern or system resources to keep running in the background.