# Search.StartNow.com Homepage Removal

Tags: desktop, web-browser

Can anyone tell me How can I remove search.startnow Homepage from browser. It is quite irritating. Need permanent solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4387/anti-virus-comparison-for-mac-os-x

Comment: I would first download [Malwarebytes](https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038479294) and scan your Mac. No need to purchase - run the free version. My Mom gets hit with these adware and malware infections every so often.