# Reinstall Safari

Tags: safari, macos

How can I reinstall Safari if one got corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

I tried that but it wouldn't install.

I had this problem in Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. I downloaded the latest version from Apple, but the installer said that I had a newer version already installed.  I had to use the application called Pacifist.  It installs applications when the installer won't.  It worked great.

Answer (score -1):

That works for me on OSX Lion with all updates:

- downoad [latest Safari](https://www.apple.com/safari/download/). Image with safari will mount automatically when download is complete otherwise you should click on it to get it mounted.
- backup existing Safari (the one that you want to replace)
- remove existing Safari using Terminal:

  `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Safari.app/`
- just install it as usual application

Comment: That's exactly what I just did with the only intention to help guy in this question:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/47217/14692?stw=1